# How to save to user documents library in WiX?

Tags: xml, msbuild, wix, installation, windows-installer

Ok, so I have a WiX installer, and currently I'm saving everything to 'ProgramFilesFolder' (`<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">`). But I'd like to install some files to the users documents, any ideas what the property for this is?

e.g. something like:

```
<Directory Id="UsersDocuments">
    //Install files here
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `PersonalFolder` that is already predefined.

You can see the full list here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties

Answer (score 0):

You want <Directory Id="PersonalFolder">.  Take a look at the System Folder Properties section here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx